# CentOS 5 Unable to Boot Not Cleanly Unmounted

Tags: centos, boot, partition, hard-disk

I'm unsure why but when trying to boot my CentOS 5 Server today it failed to boot and stops with the message

```
/dev/md1 not cleanly unmounted, check forced
```

And then it's dead in it's tracks, how can I run an fsck command to check this? I'm not getting any log in and no command exits this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reboot and at Grub press `e` key to edit the boot parameters of your kernel. Get to the kernel line and you will se something like `linux /vmlinuz... root=/dev/.... ro ...` notice the **ro** part, modify it to **rw** and add the word `sigle` before it. Then press `ctrl+x` to boot this particular, temoporary, version of options. You will enter the single user mode where you can safely run `fsck` on your devices.

Alternatively, boot from CD or USB and enter Repair mode.